# Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

When I try to remove entries from nonexistent file, I met the follow error:

> Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file
>   /usr/local/bin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth

How could I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 55):

I'm assuming you're having an issue with `pip install` or something that uses it like `tox`? This is a [known issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/542) with anaconda. You can fix the problem by adding the `--ignore-installed` option when installing your code.

Answer (score 8):

pip is looking for a file with this location. Try Creating a new one.

```
touch /usr/local/bin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth
```

[source](https://blog.jongallant.com/2018/09/solution-cannot-remove-entries-from-nonexistent-file-easy-install/)

Worked For me !!